# R: how to select rows with two conditions (bought both products)

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset which is similar to the following:

```
 ID = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3) 
 Product = c("a", "b", "c", "a","b","a","a") 
 Quantity = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
 df = data.frame(ID, Product, Quantity)

#  ID Product Quantity
#1  1       a        1
#2  2       b        1
#3  3       c        1
#4  4       a        1
#5  1       b        1
#6  2       a        1
#7  3       a        1
```

I want to select the people who purchased both product a and product b. In the case of the above example, the desired result I want is:

```
ID Product Quantity
1  a       1
2  b       1
1  b       1
2  a       1
```

I cannot recall a function that does this for me. What I can think of is through loop but I am hoping to find a more succinct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    filter(Product %in% c('a','b')) %>% # Grab only desired products
    group_by(ID)                    %>% # For each ID...
    filter(n() > 1)                 %>% # Only grab IDs where the count >1
    ungroup                             # Remove grouping.

## # A tibble: 4 x 3
##      ID Product Quantity
##   <dbl>  <fctr>    <dbl>
## 1     1       a        1
## 2     2       b        1
## 3     1       b        1
## 4     2       a        1
```

**Edit**

Here is a slightly more concise `dplyr` version using `any` (similar to how Psidom used it in the `data.table` solution):

```
df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(all(c('a','b') %in% as.character(Product))) %>%
    ungroup
```

Answer (score 6):

With `ave`:

```
df[
 with(df, ave(as.character(Product), ID, FUN=function(x) all(c("a","b") %in% x) ))=="TRUE",
]
#  ID Product Quantity
#1  1       a        1
#2  2       b        1
#5  1       b        1
#6  2       a        1
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - I never change defaults outside of declaring them formally within a script. Too much potential to break code being shared with others based on assuming their setup is the same as mine.

Comment: @Gregor - because `ave` converts the logical result of the `FUN=` back to `character`, which means I can't compare with `TRUE`, but rather `"TRUE"`

Comment: How annoying! Look like `ave` coerces the result to the same type as the first input.

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(c("a", "b") %in% Product)], ID]

#   ID Product Quantity
#1:  1       a        1
#2:  1       b        1
#3:  2       b        1
#4:  2       a        1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = "Product")[c("a", "b")][, if(uniqueN(Product)==2) .SD , ID]
#   ID Product Quantity
#1:  1       a        1
#2:  1       b        1
#3:  2       a        1
#4:  2       b        1
```